# In Solidity, is it possible to convert bytes calldata to a struct while keeping it as calldata?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

is it possible to convert bytes calldata to a struct while keeping it as calldata?

For example, I have struct:

```
struct C {
    uint256 a;
    uint256 b;
}
```

I am trying to do this:

```
function test(bytes calldata d) external view returns (C calldata c) {
    assembly {
        c.offset := d.offset
    }
}
```

However, I get this error: "TypeError: The suffix ".offset" is not supported by this variable or type."

The above does work when converting from bytes calldata to bytes calldata.

Any help is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. `calldata` is an immutable data location. Like `memory` it is temporary. `calldata` is used for gas savings.

If you are not going to modify the function argument use `calldata` because it saves gas. Otherwise use `memory` keyword